# Scripting a repetitive gdb job

Tags: c, bash, gdb

I want to do the same repetitive job in gdb across a bunch of different files. Namely,

```
bash$ gdb ./file1

... gdb starts up ...

gdb$ b *0xdeadbeef
gdb$ r < file2

... some output prints ...

gdb$ x/3a $esp

...  some addresses print ...
```

Is there some way I can script this? Starting up gdb via a script is easy, but passing commands to gdb and getting their output isn't obvious to me. Would I use redirection?

Comment: As I recall, doesn't gdb read commands from .gdbinit in the current working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a shell trick to pass multiple `gdb` commands in sequence, new-line separated to standard input of `gdb`, for it to consume. For e.g. for a single file just do

```
printf '%s\n' 'b *0xdeadbeef' 'r < file2' 'x/3a $esp' | gdb ./file1
```

For multiple input files, and feeding one file to `gdb` at a time, starting with name `file*`. Use an appropriate glob expression based on your actual filename

```
for file in file*; do
    printf '%s\n' 'b *0xdeadbeef' 'r < file2' 'x/3a $esp' | gdb "$file"
done
```

Comment: The format can simply be `'%s\n'`; `printf` itself will reuse the format until the arguments are exhausted.

Comment: @chepner: Yes just wanted to be explicit with the args. But fewer seems neater

Comment: Thank you @Inian this solution is great. :)